# rsync: Unknown --usermap name on receiver for AD user

Tags: rsync, samba4

I'm trying to move files to a new fileserver which is a samba4 domain member using `rsync -a`.
Unfortunately the uid and gid are not mapped correctly. The files on the target get the uid from the source. So I tried to force the correct mapping by using `--usermap=3000019:'DOMAIN\myuser'` but then I get

```
Unknown --usermap name on receiver: DOMAIN\myuser
```

uid and gid mapping is working as expected:

```
getent passwd 'DOMAIN\myuser'
DOMAIN\myuser:*:10001105:10000514:My User:/share/homes/DOMAIN/myuser:/bin/false
```

or

```
id 'DOMAIN\myuser
uid=10001105(DOMAIN\myuser) gid=10000514(DOMAIN\domain users)
```

Does anyone know how to handle domain users with rsync correctly?